# Surjective map onto a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $E_0$ and $E$ be arbitrary sets, $\eta$ is a continuous and surjective map from $E_0$ to $E$.

Suppose that $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert space of real-valued functions on $E$, and define $\mathcal{H}^{(\eta)}$ by $\{g\circ \eta:g\in\mathcal{H}\}$ to be a space of real-valued functions on $E_0$, then

> can we say that $\mathcal{H}^{(\eta)}$ is a Hilbert space of real-valued functions on $E_0$?

Comment: What does "Hilbert space on X" mean? I've never seen this. Is it an index set for an orthonormal basis? Please clarify?

Comment: Thanks, I meant the Hilbert space of real-valued functions on an arbitrary set $E$.

Comment: With counting measure on $E$, then? So the Hilbert space does have an orthonormal basis indexed by $E$, namely, the functions $f_x$ that are $f_x(y)=0$ for $y\not=x$, and $f_x(x)=1$?

Comment: ... and common notation would be $\ell^2_E$, if my speculation is correct.

Comment: Yes, that'd be right.

Comment: If $E_0$ and $E$ are arbitrary, the it makes no sense to talk about continuous function between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Take $E_0 = \mathbb N, E = \{1\}$ and $\eta(n) = 1$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, $\mathcal H = \ell^2(E) = \mathbb R$ and $\mathcal H^\eta$ isn't even a subset of $\ell^2(E_0)$.